# What are some techniques for swapping out sample data in Redux/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to develop my React/Redux app without touching the actual server API part of the application. Ideally, I'd develop against a set of JSON files. What's the best way or least complicated way to do this? Ideally with some sort of plugin? Here's my current thinking:

1. Create a separate API server that spins up only in a development environment and point my client-side app to that.
2. In my actual middleware server (Express) do a check and if not in production serve up the JSON files. I don't like the idea that possibly in a higher environment sample data can be served up and this feels hacky.

Both will work, but feel messy. I don't want a separate "fake" API server as that creates the possibility that the routes I call might have a typo or be different. If Javascript had proper interfaces this would mitigate this but still feels messy.

Here's a simplified overview of my environment which differs a bit from what you would see an example in that I have the serverside code and clientside code rather separate:

```
/my-cool-project
 /api (express, no clientside)
 /client-side-app-1 (react/redux)
 /client-side-app-2 (react/redux)
 /vendor (all libraries go in here so they can be shared across projects)
 /release (upon building currently everything gets bundled up and this is what gets copied to the server)
```

I suppose this is not really a react/redux problem but this is the first time where my project is 90% client-side. In a .NET MVC app, I would swap out the dataprovider via IOC using build transforms and point to what I wanted it to point to (flat files, different sql database, web service, etc.).

Comment: My preference would be to have two different implementations of a `Request` API. One would do HTTP request, another would read a file and map requests to static responses. But it's totally your decision. Most he testing frameworks have "mocks", maybe you could grab some ideas from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the more traditional developers at our company have of late been making the transition from .NET MVC apps to react/redux so here is the solution we came up for them. It's just one of many possible implementations.

**REST API**

They first learned to make RESTful APIs as some where still using archaic, non-specific APIs. From your mention of "JSON files" I assume you're on the right path but I'd double check to make sure the API is truly RESTful. The reason why is that you'll eventually need a way to handle both POST and GETs as your application gains complexity.

**Separation of services**

The next step was to completely separate the service back-end from the front-end meaning separate server instances. I recommend a simple Node server but almost anything will do. The key here is to understand environment variables in the front-end server.

With environment variables, you can export prod and dev versions of the web app without ever deploying dev code to a production release, as you correctly point out. With environment variables at hand, let's call it `env`, we recommended dispatching an action to store it in the store as this is an app-wide state variable used by any component needing to make a service call.

**Format service calls**

The last piece is using `env` to formulate your service calls. We use `fetch` to make the service calls (highly recommend it for its ease of use with CORS and Cookies) and have a `utilities.js` file that "generates" the endpoint URLs. If you create your API carefully and RESTfully, you'll notice that it's very easy to create what you're suggesting in the following format:

**Example**

Say your production services are hosted at

```
const PROD_ENDPOINT = 'exampleDomain.com:8080'
```

and a sample route to fetch at

```
const sampleEndpoint = 'sample/documents'
```

When a component (which has access to `env`) needs to fetch that endpoint's data, we call on the util function to compose the URL using `env`:

```
function composeURL(endpoint, env) {
    if (env === 'prod') {
         return `${PROD_ENDPOINT}/${sampleEndpoint}` // note I'm using ES6 string interpolation
    } else {
         return `file://some_path_to_your_JSON_files/${sampleEndpoint}`
    }
}
```

We didn't use this `composeURL` function quite like this because in our case our environments determined which hosted services to hit rather than local JSON files. If your only need for fetching "local JSON files" is for development, I would recommend running your dev services locally alongside your web app. Fetching local files directly can get messy very quickly.

Hope this helps and good luck!